# Kentor AuthService HTTPModule- ADFS Login Exception

Tags: single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, adfs, kentor-authservices

In our ASP.Net project, I am using 'Kentor.AuthServices.HTTPModule' and have configured ADFS.

Have given the SAML Assertion Consumer Binding as "redirect" and Trusted-URL as "ourSiteUrl". If the user is not signed in, it will automatically redirect to ADFS login page. When login is successfull, it will redirect to "ourSiteURL/AuthServices/Acs?SAMLResponse=..." and it throws an Exception in the page :**"Kentor.AuthServices.Exceptions.InvalidSignatureException: Cannot verify signature of message from unknown sender win-3obaenpbsol.dc10.inapp.com/adfs/services/trust."**

The exception image is also attached. Please help..

[ADFS Login Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KfhZr.png)

Comment: Don't submit the same question twice. This is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38433399/kentor-httpmodule-adfs-login-samlresponse-error/38453788#38453788

Comment: Maybe can you deleted the question...