# Kentor HTTPModule- ADFS Login SAMLResponse ERROR

Tags: asp.net, saml, saml-2.0, adfs, kentor-authservices

In our ASP.Net project, I am using `Kentor.AuthServices.HTTPModule` and have configured ADFS.

Have given the SAML Assertion Consumer Binding as "redirect" and Trusted-URL as "ourSiteUrl".

After ADFS login is successful, it will redirect to `ourSiteURL/AuthServices/Acs?SAMLResponse=...` and it throws an Exception

> Kentor.AuthServices.Exceptions.InvalidSignatureException: Cannot
>   verify signature of message from unknown sender
>   win-3obaenpbsol.dc10.inapp.com/adfs/services/trust.

What could be the reason for this issue?

Comment: full code for `Kentor.AuthServices.HTTPModule` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason is that AuthServices does not recognize the Idp with entity id `win-3obaenpbsol.dc10.inapp.com/adfs/services/trust`.

I also see that you are using the Redirect binding when sending the response to AuthServices, which is not supported. That is a setting you need to change on the ADFS side.

To make configuration easier, please use metadata. AuthServices supports importing ADFS metadata and AuthServices generates metadata that ADFS can consume at `ourSiteURL/AuthServices/`.

Comment: We changed the SAML Assertion Consumer Bindings in ADFS to "Post". Now we are able to get the claims details in our
application. But when  we tried to give the  encription certificate in the ADFS have got an exception "The specified network password is not correct."
So we remove the certificate from ADFS to make this work

Comment: How do we logOut from the application , we tried "~/AuthServices/Logout?ReturnUrl=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(Page.ResolveUrl("~/?Status=LoggedOut")) but it does not work. Can you please help to resolve the logout and certificate issue? Also, can we load the serviceCertificates from certificate store.